# Filter list items with radiobuttons in android

Tags: android, listview, filter, radio-button

Lets say I have three radiobuttons (All, Fruits, Vegetables) and I want to filter items on a list based on which radionbutton is checked. For example, if the user checks the "Fruits" radiobutton, only the items on the list that are fruits should be displayed.
This is my CustomListAdapter, the listItems and descriptions are filled with information about fruits and vegetables.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listItems;
    private final ArrayList<String> descriptions;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> descriptions, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listItems) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_view, descriptions);

        this.context = context;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null,true);

        TextView txtDescription = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView txtDetails = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.details);
        TextView txtDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView txtValue = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.value);

        txtDescription.setText(descriptions.get(position));
        txtDetails.setText(listItems.get(position).get(0));
        txtDate.setText(listItems.get(position).get(1));
        txtValue.setText(listItems.get(position).get(2));
        return rowView;

    }
}
```

And this is the part of the code relevant to the question:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    new GetInfoTask().execute();

    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.filter);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            // do something to filter items on listview
            if (checkedId==R.id.all) {

            } else if (checkedId==R.id.fruits) {

            } else if (checkedId==R.id.vegetables) {

            }
        }
    });
}

private void display() {

    final CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, descriptions, itemsList);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

I probably have to use notifyDataSetChanged to display only the items I want, but how to filter them with radiobuttons?

Answer (score 1):

```
You can add list base on selected group from radio button 

RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.filter);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            // do something to filter items on listview
            if (checkedId==R.id.all) {
                    display(filerlist,discriptipnlist);

            } else if (checkedId==R.id.fruits) {

                display(filerlist,discriptipnlist);

            } else if (checkedId==R.id.vegetables) {
                  display(filerlist,discriptipnlist);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void display(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> itemsList,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> descriptions) {

    final CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, descriptions, itemsList);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

i hope this will work for you
```